# How can I get labels of a sub folder under a team project using command line tool TF.exe?

Tags: command-line, tfs

We have TFS version control in which the following folder structure is adopted.

The following is the folder structure that we use:

[image]

In the above image, `delta` is the TFS server name, `TempProjects` is the project collection and `DetBarShapeEngine` is one of the team project. `Main` is the branch name and `ProjectSource` is a special folder under which all files managed by development team are stored. We label at the `ProjectSource` level and hence it is a kind of root folder for every project source.

When I ran `tf labels /collection:"https://delta:443/tfs/TempProjects" /owner:*`, I saw a huge list of labels from all the project collections including `DetBarShapeEngine`.

I modified the above command line to include the team project in the project collection URL `tf labels /collection:"https://delta:443/tfs/TempProjects/DetBarShapeEngine" /owner:*`, I receive:

> TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server .... ....
>   Technical information (for administrator): The remote server returned
>   an error: (404) Not Found.

I tried increasing the depth of the path of the project collection URL till `ProjectSource`, but I still get the same 404 error.

**Question:**
**How do I get labels of a sub folder under a team project?**

Note:

1. I cannot change this folder structure for any reason what so ever.
2. We use TFS 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling a lot, I stumbled on a blog showing sample about using scope in some other command. I tried to use that scope string to `TF labels` command and it was a success!

Here is the command line that I used:

```
tf labels /collection:"https://delta:443/tfs/CadsProjects" *@$/DetBarShapeEngine/Main/ProjectSource /owner:*
```